# How to use the "Alt + tab" shortcut in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

```
set test = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
test.SendKeys"%{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

The second line shortcut command does not work! Someone help me?

Comment: For me it's works this code in one line if you want : `set test =createobject("wscript.shell"):wscript.sleep 500:test.sendkeys"%{TAB}":wscript.echo "Done"`

Answer (score 4):

when you run your VBScript via a batch file or CMD,

one tab brings you back where you were before running the script

and you think nothing happens.

Try alt + TAB + TAB

or more tabs

`set test = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
test.SendKeys"%({TAB}{TAB})"
WScript.Sleep 500`

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"

Set WSHShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`WshShell.SendKeys "^%{TAB}"` Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To switch fast between last apps, use:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "%^{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 45
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

and save as appswitch.vbs using notepad.

Answer (score -3):

After trying various methods stated here I've come up with something that seems to work.

```
set wsh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wsh.SendKeys "^%({TAB}{TAB})"
wscript.sleep 100
wsh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```